# Retrieving JSON data and display in a table with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am very new to programming with jQuery. I've spent quite a while trying to move forward with this, and I've managed to get some of it done. But I've really hit a wall and I can't seem to find help from anywhere/anyone.

**Scenario:**

- I am using a select box to store different music genres, which I have retrieved via PHP/MySQL.

  ```
      <?php
  include 'connectingDB.php';
  $catSQL = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY catDesc";
  $queryresult = mysql_query($catSQL)
  or die (mysql_error());
  echo "<select id= \"catID\">";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
      $catID = $row['catID'];
      $catDesc = $row['catDesc'];


      echo "<option value = \"$catID\">$catDesc</option>\n";

  }
  echo "</select>";
  mysql_free_result($queryresult);
  mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
  ```
- When I click on a genre, I want all of the related CDs and CD information to be retrieved in JSON format and dynamically displayed in a table using AJAX (below the select box on that same page)

  ```
  <?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  include 'connectingDB.php';
  $category = $_REQUEST['catname'];
  $sql = "SELECT `CDID`, `CDTitle`, `CDYear`, `pubID`, `CDPrice`
          FROM `tiptop_cd`
          INNER JOIN tiptop_category
          ON tiptop_cd.catID=tiptop_category.catID
          WHERE catDesc = '{$category}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $returned[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($returned);
  ```

  ?>
- All of the above code works on its own. But I'm looking to connect it all together. I think it needs to be via an `onchange` event in jQuery?
- I've got an `alert` to pop up after clicking a category, but that's as far as I can get..

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#catID").change(function(){
  alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
  });
  ```

Does it need to be in a `foreach` loop? Or a `foreach` within a `foreach`?

**To summarize, I'm trying to understand how to: display the cds and cd information that are related to the specific category that is currently selected, in a dynamic table with ajax**

Any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use AJAX for this purpose. Ajax will allow you to send the user's choice (ie. the dropdown selection) to a back-end PHP file.

The PHP file will process the received data (ie. the user's choice) and perform a database lookup based on that info. It will take the result from db and construct (in a variable) the required HTML for the table, and then `echo` back the contents of that variable -- which will be received in the AJAX procedure's `success:` (or `.done()` to use promise syntax) function.

*INSIDE* the success/done function, you can use received data. For example, you can use the jQuery `.html()` method to replace the contents of a specified DIV with the HTML you received.

My approach would differ from the other proposed solutions in the following ways:

1. I prefer using the full `$.ajax()` syntax, as it allows for greater structure, which makes it somewhat easier to understand/manipulate at first. Note that `.post()`, `.get()` and `.load()` are all shortcut forms of `$.ajax()` that make certain assumptions in order to streamline the process. I suggest learning the `$.ajax()` format first, and then utilizing the others. Having done gazillions of ajax blocks myself, I continue to use `$.ajax()` most times. Perhaps it is a preference, but I find it much easier to use/read/review -- and it also allows additional params that the others do not, which makes it more flexible and useful**.
2. It is necessary to use a second .PHP file to act as your ajax processor. You cannot use the same .PHP file that contains your AJAX code block. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572601/change-php-variable-with-ajax/20572741#20572741).
3. The place to construct the HTML table is in the PHP (processor file). As mentioned, construct it all in a variable and then, at the end, output that variable:

Note how the `$r` variable is constructed in the while loop, and only ECHOed out at the end.

```
$aContact_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contacts`");
$r = '<table>';
while ($rrow = mysql_fetch_array($aContact_info)) {
    $r .= '<tr>
            <td>
                Name:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="'.$rrow['first_name'].'"> 
                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="'.$rrow['last_name'].'">
            </td>
            <td>
                Email:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="'.$rrow['email1'].'">
            </td>
            <td>
                Cell Phone:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" value="'.$rrow['cell_phone'].'">
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
$r .= '</table>';
echo $r;
```

Here are some examples that should help:

[Simple explanation of AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221813/place-php-results-inside-html-page/17221883#17221883)
[Example with MySQL lookup in PHP Processor file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

---

** Differences between `.get()` and `.post()` and `$.ajax()`:

[GET vs POST in AJAX calls](http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/key-differences-post/)
[Kevin Chisholm](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/jquery-ajax-get-post-difference/)
[Sychronous AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209097/what-is-the-difference-between-asyncfalse-and-asynctrue-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this can get you started

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#catID").change(function () {
        $.post("index.php?catname=" + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            var table = $('<table></table>'); //create table
            $.each(data, function (index, value) { //loop through array
                var row = $('<tr></tr>'); //create row
                var cell1 = $("<td></td>").val(value.CDID); //create cell append value
                //etc
                row.append(cell1); //append cell to row
                table.append(row); //append row to table
            });
            $('#div').append(table); //append table to your dom wherever you want
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've tried implementing this code and altering it accordingly, but nothing seems to happen. Here is the site. http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w10012836/fanzine/fanzine.php  Here is the pastebin for the js aswell http://pastebin.com/TKaCbxNK

Answer (score 0):

another (faster) method would be to return an html table as a string and inject it into the DOM. generate the table in your PHP handler, then do $('#div').load('/index.php?catname=catname'); or do $.get like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#catID").change(function () {
        $.get({               
            url: 'index.php',
            data: { catname: $(this).val() }
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
               $('#div').html(html);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) { displayErrorMessage("Error: \n\nreadyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText, 'nosave'); }
        });
    });
 });
```