# How to refresh specific div using Javascript/Jquery with the variables on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a variable **$salary** which is dynamic. How can I refresh specific **div** every 5seconds.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="<?php echo $filename.'.jpg'; ?>" />
        <p id="salary"><?php echo $salary; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any javascript/jquery way to refresh **#salary** only. Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change php variable with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572601/change-php-variable-with-ajax)

Comment: If you need to keep the server and client data in sync to this level I'd suggest using WebSockets instead. AJAX polling scales terribly badly, and will eventually DDOS your server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute an ajax call:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'path/to/asyncHalndler.php',
        data: { ... },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#salary').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Execute ajax call every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
    ajaxCall();
},5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var salary = document.getElementById('salary');
```

Now, the value of your variable salary will be the DOM node where you would like to change the value. When you get new data, you can refresh text inside your p tag with salary id by adding `salary.innerText = yourNewValue;`

This is pure JavaScript way of updating that element with id.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an jquery ajax call for that.
first you should create php file **get_salary.php** where you send id from jquery ajax if you want to update the salary for unique id:

in get_salary.php you need to get salary from database so the code in this php file will be like that

```
$id = $_POST['ID']
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sallaries WHERE id='$id'") or die("Can't connect");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)
$salary = $fetch['salary']
echo $salary
```

after that you will need javascript file(e.g script.js) from where you will send the request and id to the get_salary.php and grab the data from it, after that you will be able to update salary in html, so code in javascript file will be like that:

```
function updateSalary(){}
var id=25;
$.ajax({
    url: "get_salary.php",
    type: 'POST',

    //sending id
    data:'id='+id,
    success: function(result){

        //updating html
        $("#salary").html(result);
    }
});
}

//setting interval to update in every second
setInterval(updateSalary, 1000)
```

so it will update your salary in the div

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use ajax way. But if u are looking for a very simple solution then jQuery .load will be the best

```
setInterval($("#salary").load("<url to get the value>"), 1000);
```